# hadoop ClassNotFoundException when running start-all.sh

Tags: hadoop, classnotfoundexception

I tried to run ./hadoop start-all.sh
Unfortunately this error is thrown

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: start/all/sh
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: start.all.sh
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: start.all.sh. Program will exit.
```

I though it might have been the hadoop path but that does not seem to fix the issue. The path that i set in the hadoop-env.sh is /usr/local/hadoop/bin`.

I looked at other posts with simular titles
[Hadoop: strange ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976846/hadoop-strange-classnotfoundexceptionsolved)

what is considered the main class. I tried changing the path to /usr/local/hadoop/bin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a shell script. >> start-all.sh should do. You do not need hadoop. You can find more information here. http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.19.2/quickstart.html

Comment: You tried with absolute path as suggested by Sandeep? Do `printenv` and see if the path variable has the directory that contains start-all.sh.

Comment: it runs but /usr/bin/env is not found

Comment: i dont know what happened but i cant even login now

Answer (score 1):

Just run as follows
/path/to/Hadoop/home/bin/start-all.sh
In your case 
/user/local/hadoop/bin/start-all.sh

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already in **/hadoop/bin** folder. You no need to give again **./hadoop start-all.sh**

instead just give **./start-all.sh**

It will not throw any error and it will start your hadoop process.